# Find If HashMap contains a value or not and delete that value only

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, hashmap

Suppose we have the below code:

```
public class HashMapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add("A");
        al.add("B");
        al.add("C");
        map1.put("1", al);
    }
}
```

At first the `HashMap` would be looking like:

```
{{"1"},{"A","B","C"}}
```

Now I want to find the value `"B"` in `HashMap` and want to delete this value from `arraylist` which is present in `hashmap`.

So that the final result would be looking like:

```
{{"1"},{"A","C"}}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: it is a trivial problem, what have you tried?

Comment: However a HashMap isn't particularly of value for this requirement

Comment: Simple enough code, although the fact that you'll need a loop within a loop should be a hint that maybe you have the wrong data structure.

Answer (score 3):

Use a HashSet instead of an ArrayList inside the HasMap.

```
HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
HashSet<String> al = new HashSet<>();
al.add("A");
al.add("B");
al.add("C");
map1.put("1", al);
```

Remove by:

```
map1.get("1").remove("B")
```

Comment: Can you please modify the code and show me how it will help us?

Comment: Suppose we don't know the key and the value is present for more than one key... we want to delete that value for all the keys which contains that value.

Comment: Using hashset might not be a solution if we need to store the "value" more than once in the collecction

Comment: If multiple values are required then use Hashmap inside a hashmap

Answer (score 1):

Currently Java does not provide the support of removing an element using its value in `hashmap` so you have to iterate all the elements and fetch the `arraylist` and check that value is present or not if its present than remove that value. if the value is static you can use `map1.get("1").remove("B")`  and if its dynamic than provide an input source and then iterate the map and than iterate the `arraylist` check if value persists if so than delete it `